# MEF with open generic type

Tags: c#, mef

I have these interfaces

```
public interface IImageSource<T>
{
    // Properties
    T OutputFrame { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Guid Guid { get; set; }

    // Events
    event EventHandler<DmEventArgs<T>> NewFrameOutput;

    // Methods
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
    void Initialize();
}

public interface IImageFilter<TIn, TOut>
{
    // Properties
    TIn Input { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Guid Guid { get; set; }

    TOut Process(TIn frame);
}
```

Based on these interfaces i created classes like

```
[Export(typeof(IImageSource<>))]
public class AForgeImageSource : IImageSource<Image<Bgr, byte>>
{
    // Implementation...
}

[Export(typeof(IImageFilter<,>))]
public class AnotherFilter1 : IImageFilter<Image<Bgr, byte>, Image<Bgr, byte>>
{
    // Implementation...
}
```

**The question is how do i use MEF to fufill all the object that implement IImageSource into an observable collection ImageSources?** or how to use MEF to get all the object that implement IImageFilter into an observable collection ImageFilters?

I tried the below but not working. BTW, i'm using MEF and MEF Contrib.

```
    [ImportMany]
    public ObservableCollection<IImageSource<object>> ImageSources
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IImageFilter<object, object>))]
    public ObservableCollection<IImageFilter<object, object>> ImageFilters
    {
        // Implementation...
    }
```

The collection of the ImageFilters can be make up of

```
IImageFilter<string, string>
IImageFilter<string, int>
IImageFilter<int, double>
```

and here's the code I get MEF to do the composition.

```
public void LoadPluginList()
{
    var pluginsDirectoryPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Plugins";
    //var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    //var genericCatalog = new GenericCatalog();

    var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginsDirectoryPath);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Outside of 'typof', you cannot use generic types _without_ the type parameters. Therefore, you cannot create a contract name using the method signature alone, try specifying the import type in the `Import` attribute.

Comment: I wanted to do the import without the type because i would like to have all the class that implement the interface to be group and fulfill. Make sense?

Comment: I understand what you want to do but there are limitation in how you can use c# generics. You cannot cast to an instance of `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: I think this can help cast it to IEnumerable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368975/observablecollection-of-open-generic-type

Answer (score 2):

Here are some samples

### These do not work

Cardinality mistmatch results in `TestModule` being rejected.

1.

```
[Export(typeof(IEnumerable<>))]
public class IntegerCollection: List<int>
{

}

[ModuleExport(typeof(TestModule))]
public class TestModule : Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModule
{
    [Import(typeof(IEnumerable<>))]
    public IEnumerable<int> Integers
    {
        get { return m_Integers; }
        set { m_Integers = value; }
    } private IEnumerable<int> m_Integers;


    public void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

2.

```
[Export(typeof(IEnumerable<>))]
public class IntegerCollection: List<int>
{

}

[ModuleExport(typeof(TestModule))]
public class TestModule : Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModule
{
    [Import]
    public IEnumerable<int> Integers
    {
        get { return m_Integers; }
        set { m_Integers = value; }
    } private IEnumerable<int> m_Integers;


    public void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

### This one works

```
[Export(typeof(IEnumerable<object>))]
public class IntegerCollection: List<int>
{

}

[ModuleExport(typeof(TestModule))]
public class TestModule : Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModule
{
    [Import(typeof(IEnumerable<object>))]
    public IEnumerable<int> Integers
    {
        get { return m_Integers; }
        set { m_Integers = value; }
    } private IEnumerable<int> m_Integers;


    public void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

Why? Well, `int` is assignable *from* `object`, so i can export `IEnumerable<int>` as `IEnumerable<object>` with no problem.

However, if i exported an `IEnumerable<double>` and `IEnumerable<object>` *instead*, it will fail because `double` is not assignable to `int`.

My recommendations:

- Consider a non-generic base interface
- Import your filters to a property of type IEnumerable but use a contract name string to for the exports and import definitions. e.g. `[Export("IMAGE_FILTERS")]`

Comment: After some research, i resorted to use Non-Generic base interface. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, [Export("IMAGE_FILTERS")] won't solve if other conditions are not met. Those conditions are discussed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (under Export/Import Mismatches) for those who are interested. Thanks for the help Gusdor.

Answer (score 0):

The export and import type does not match. Try

```
[Export(typeof(IImageFilter<object,object>))]
public class AnotherFilter1 : IImageFilter<Image<Bgr, byte>, Image<Bgr, byte>>
{
// Implementation...
}
```

Comment: tried. Not working. I believe that's because MEF pick up the meta data at runtime. That means ImageFilter<Image<Bgr, byte>> got picked up instead of ImageFilter<object, object>

Comment: try to debug your catalog, see if it has the same Export Definition. it resolved pretty well in my prototype.